# Master don't receive the minon key

Tags: saltstack

Well, i installed salt-minion in some computers, but it just don't send any key to be acepted, i reinstall the salt-minion three times in each computer, and it doesn't work, somebody can help?

No minions matched the target. No command was sent, no jid was assigned.
ERROR: No return received

Comment: Check your firewall ACL and IPTables rules.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering, I just realize that i was installing the wrong version, x64 in a system x32, but a curious thing is that the instalation wasn't stopped, anyway, trouble solved!